# How to add a WPF Button to add content to a List inside an ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, observablecollection

From a Database I am receiving a List with multiple Properties. One of those Properties is again a List of an Appendix Object containing ID Information and an Image.
I converted that List into an ObservableCollection and bound it to a WPF ListBox. Using a DataTemplate I show this content. Inside the DataTemplate I now have an ItemControl bound to the Inner-List (my Appendix with none, one or multiple entries):

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Reports}">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Content="Report Date:" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                <Label Content="{Binding ReportDate.Date, StringFormat=dd.MM.yyyy , ConverterCulture=de-DE}"/>
                <Label Content="Comment:" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                <Label Content="{Binding Comment}"/>
            </StackPanel>

            //Here I would like to have a Button to add a Picture into the Appendix List

            <ItemsControl x:Name="SelectedOnlyListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Appendix}" Visibility="Collapsed">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <VirtualizingStackPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Source="{Binding Picture}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>

        </StackPanel>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" TargetName="SelectedOnlyListBox" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

My question is, how do I get the current Object via Binding into my Code. Because I will have multiple Buttons for one outer List (Reports) entry. But the Button should only add into the proper Inner List (Appendix).

Additional info: I am using the MVVM-Light Toolkit.
Thank you very much.

Edit: I forgot to mention that the first List is one of many Properties of a Detail class which again comes in a List of all Details. So with my DataContext already got a Property "SelectedDetail". This one I know...
But how do I now match the specific Button of each SelectedDetail.Report to my SelectedDetail.Reports.Appendix?

Comment: You can bind the Seleted ListBox item on ListBox (let's say SelectedReport). So SelectedReport.Appendix can be used to add a picture into it.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I forgot to mention that the whole ListBox is already a property of a so called "Detail" class. So I already got a Property SelectedDetail which contains many properties inclusive the Reports List which contains then the Appendix List... So my problem is to get this one more level.

Comment: Please post your corresponding model / view-model code. It's hard to understand from your description what the problem is.